# Parse &lt; and &gt; as <> in BeautifulSoup without re-parsing?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I return `<b>bold</b>` in this example without first prettifying the soup?

```
html_content = "<div>This is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; text.</div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, parser='html.parser')
print(soup.find('b'))  # outputs None
```

Everything works as expected if I prettify the soup first, and then re-parse it.

```
html_content = "<div>This is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; text.</div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, parser='html.parser')
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.prettify(formatter=None), parser='html.parser')
print(soup.find('b'))  # outputs <b>bold</b>
```

But is there a way of doing this without parsing twice?

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with BeautifulSoup, but can you do something like this: `BeautifulSoup(html_content, parser='html.parser').prettify(formatter=None)`?

Comment: It's not correct parsing if you treat them as syntactic rather than literal. `&lt;` is the text character `<`, not the XML/HTML syntax `<`; moreover, content gets escaped this way because it's _supposed_ to be exempt from parsing as syntax (think of attacker-provided data adding `<script>` tags pulling in content from servers they control).

Comment: Unfortunately not, `soup.prettify()` returns a string, not the actual `BeautifulSoup` object.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah sorry, it was probably not correct of me to say that what I want to achieve is "expected" behaviour in general but in this case it's what I want to happen :)

Comment: I also want to add that this is the content that I fetch from the website, so the website has escaped `<>`, and it's not something `BeautifulSoup` does for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find encoded `<b>` inside the `<div>` you need to parse the text inside the `<div>`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = "<div>This is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; text.</div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

print(soup.div.text)
```

This prints:

```html
This is <b>bold</b> text.
```

---

To find the `<b>` you do then:

```
b = BeautifulSoup(soup.div.text, "html.parser").b
print(b)
```

Prints:

```html
<b>bold</b>
```

---

**OR:** Use [`html.unescape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) first:

```py
from html import unescape

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = "<div>This is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; text.</div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(unescape(html_content), "html.parser")

print(soup.b)
```

Prints:

```
<b>bold</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on my end:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = '<div>This is <b>bold</b> text.</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, features='html.parser')
bold_tag = soup.find('b')
if bold_tag is not None:
    bold_text = bold_tag.get_text()
    print(bold_text)
else:
    print('No bold tags found')
```